# No FFmpeg Video In Panel (ver 2.79) in Fedora Linux

Tags: video, linux

I am a beginner and have managed to create "Star Wars Crawl" in version 2.79 on Fedora 27,  but cannot see any FFmpeg output option.

I have gstreamer and VLC installed and can properly play MP4 sample files in it.

As a last resort I reinstalled Blender.

What do I need to do to render my animation in MPEG format?

Comment: What is 1.79 version? Maybe 2.79? Do you have ffmpeg installed in your system?

Comment: Sorry it was a typo,  I am using Version 2.79 and have ffmpeg installed on Fedora 26.

Comment: Fedora Linux does not install ffmpeg by defalult. You need to install it yourself. https://blog.hostonnet.com/ffmpeg

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Limited set of output codecs in Fedora Linux. How can I enable others?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28681/limited-set-of-output-codecs-in-fedora-linux-how-can-i-enable-others) or [How can I enable mp4/h264 as an output option in Fedora Linux?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47166/how-can-i-enable-mp4-h264-as-an-output-option-in-fedora-linux/47310#47310)

Answer (score 0):

Here's my approach (right or wrong, its what I do):

*A I try to find a setting in the output dropdown that gives me the following encoding options:

*B Pick MPEG-4 (if you need to revert back to MPEG-2 That should still work, just make sure that you go the extra step in the Audio Codec section below this section and set it to mp3 - hint if I am also rendering out sound I set this anyway).

*C I personally try to use the H.264 codec, that does **NOT** imply that you should, its just what I do. To get a better sense of the codecs, and their respective containers, I recommend looking at to place in the manual.

[Place #1](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/output/video.html)

[Place #2](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/data_system/files/media/video_formats.html)

*OUTPUT Whatever combination I pick (If I'm still unsure about it), I can see if it is going to work or not, by hard-coding the file extension of my desire, cross my fingers, and render. Sometimes I will get a default extension like *.dvd; sometimes my first extension may not work (such as *.mp4), so I try *.mpg, *.mpeg, etc...

The process seems pretty effective for me.

**I will recommend this:**

Try to stay away from getting lost in codec availability for your OS for now, as that is a huge topic, and you may even get lost in it. Your Blender implementation of it can probably be solved a lot quicker.

[image]

Comment: I do not have any "FFmpeg video" option,  when I left click the file format box I only get 3 options for "Movie": AVI JPEG, AVI RAW and Frame Server.  If I have FFmpeg installed and can play a sample MP4 file in VLC I cannot understand why is it not an option in Blender!?

Comment: The problem was that Fedora does not default to an active ffmpeg! I downloaded the .gz version and made a Desktop link to it.  I now have the relevant formats.  I had not realized Fedora defaulted to limited formats! I just thought for completeness I would add this comment because it might help others! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to install **ffmpeg**, if you didn't do this. **ffmpeg** contents non-free libraries, so it doesn't install by default (instead of Ubuntu).

```
su
rpm -Uvh http://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/fedora/rpmfusion-free-release-stable.noarch.rpm http://download1.rpmfusion.org/nonfree/fedora/rpmfusion-nonfree-release-stable.noarch.rpm
yum install ffmpeg
```

Comment: [root@study peter]# dnf install ffmpeg
Last metadata expiration check: 0:12:14 ago on Wed 04 Apr 2018 14:54:07 BST.
Package ffmpeg-3.3.6-1.fc26.x86_64 is already installed, skipping.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!
[root@study peter]#

Comment: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Centos