# VSE: No Audio In Rendered File, Mixdown causes crash

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor, audio

Ever since switching from Windows to Linux, I have been unable to render any videos in Blender's VSE with the audio tracks.

The audio codec is selected in the scene tab:
[image: The "Output" tab in Blender's properties panel. The container is set to MPEG-4. The video codec is set to H.264, and the audio codec is set to AAC.]

However after rendering with `Render > Render Animation` the created file has no audio data whatsoever. `ffprobe` gives this result:

```
$ ffprobe -i wheel.mp4
...snip...
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'wheel.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    date            : 2020/08/13 09:38:02
    encoder         : Lavf58.49.100
  Duration: 00:00:06.67, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 5835 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 5832 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
$
```

When I attempt to render the audio on it's own via `Render > Render Audio > Mixdown`, Blender crashes without a log file regardless of how I attempt to mixdown the file.

This is happening regardless of my choice of rendering engine, and I don't think it's an out of memory error since I have plenty of available memory before the crash and the video portion renders fine.

Has something changed between rendering files from the VSE between 2.7 and 2.8, or is there something I don't know about rendering audio in Blender on Linux that's causing a crash?

Comment: What distro are you using? Did you use a repository to install or did you download directly from blender.org?

Comment: I've had a few issues with blender on non-ubuntu based distros that were all solved by using the tarball on blender's website as opposed to the repos.

Comment: Fedora (and probably other red-hat based distros) don't have support for ffmpeg non-free libraries out of the box. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28681/limited-set-of-output-codecs-in-fedora-linux-how-can-i-enable-others

Comment: Those are fair comments. I'm running Manjaro, and using Blender from the Arch package repository. I'm not sure if this is specifically a problem with using nonfree codecs because I had this issue with VP9/Vorbis as well. I'll try with the official tarball and report back.

Comment: I'll be darned, that worked right out of the box. I'll go ahead and answer my own question I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

After [a few comments on the above post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/190886/vse-no-audio-in-rendered-file-mixdown-causes-crash#comment319808_190886) and some experimentation, it seems not all distro packages are created equal. If you're experiencing some weird bugs like this, try downloading a tarball right from [Blender.org](https://blender.org).

Comment: Packages from repositories are not created by the developers of blender, so go figure how they are compiled and what is included or left out.