# What to do when done Rendering?

Tags: rendering, workflow, video

So I've been trying to make an intro for my youtube channel and I've made it and rendered it but I don't know what to do after I'm done rendering. Can someone help me please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I upload Blender videos to Youtube?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24724/how-can-i-upload-blender-videos-to-youtube)

Answer (score 5):

## Saving a Still Image

*(Assuming you have already rendered your image - if you haven't yet, do Render > Render Image)*

From the UV/Image Editor menu, choose **Image > Save As Image**

[image: Save As Image]

You will be presented with a screen prompting you to choose the file path where you want your image to be saved.

If you ever see the file path field turn red it means a file with that name exists, and saving with that name will overwrite the existing one.

[image: File path bar red]

There are some options for file format and color information on the bottom left.

[image: Save As Image - options]

Then press the **Save As** Image button in the upper right.

[image: Save As Image button]

Clicking the "plus" button or pressing <kbd>+ =</kbd> will increment your file name by one number.

Note that Blender can also be set to [write still renders to disk](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39703/how-to-save-still-renders-straight-to-disk-like-animations/39704#39704), like it does with animations.

## Saving Animations

Specify a file path in the Render context.
Use PNG for rendering individual image frames, or a video container format such as MOV if you want a single video file.

[image: File Output path]

Specify the frame range.

[image: Start and End frames]

Choose **Render > Render Animation** or press the Animation button.

[image: Render buttons]

Comment: I just added the video info too. :-)  While OP's question was not well worded, and showed little effort, it is a very common question for beginners to have. So I hope my answer will be helpful to other newbies as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should have set the output folder in the "Render" tab so that it saves the whole video in a specific folder. I guess you'll have to render it again...

Answer (score 0):

Upload your video to [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/upload)... Then go to [YouTube Studio](https://www.youtube.com/dashboard?o=U) where you can set some [Featured Content](https://www.youtube.com/featured_content) in your channel.

But that's not a real Blender related question if you wanted only this as an answer...

Make sure, your render is in one of the [supported YouTube file formats](https://support.google.com/youtube/troubleshooter/2888402?hl=en), namely *.MOV*, *.MPEG4*, *.MP4*, *.AVI*, .WMV, .MPEGPS, .FLV, 3GPP or WebM. Only some of them are *supported* by Blender through the intenally used *ffmpeg*. It depends on your system and how Blender was compiled, but there already are [other](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/28681/2843) [questions](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/47166/2843) about this [topic](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/28839/2843)...

Consider using the [recommended upload encoding settings](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/1722171): MP4 as a Container (without Edit lists), AAC-LC as an audio Codec with Stereo or Stereo+ 5.1 and a sample rate of 96 or 48 kHz, H.264 as video codec*, if possible the same framerate as it was recorded, deinterlace your footage if possible, use a 5Mbps Video Bitrate for 720p or 8Mbps for 1080p for standard framerates (24-30) or multiply by 1.5 for high framerates (48-60) and if possible use a 16:9 aspect ratio. For Audio use 384 kbps for stereo or 128 for mono. Not everything that YouTube recommends can be set up in Blender properly, though.

*For the H.264 video codec use:

> Progressive scan (no interlacing), High Profile, 2 consecutive B frames, Closed GOP (GOP of half the frame rate), CABAC, Variable bitrate (No bitrate limit required, though we offer recommended bit rates below for reference), Chroma subsampling: 4:2:0.

To give you a few more details of what to setup in Blender for example for a 25 fps 720p video:

[image: Example Dimension, Output & Encoding Settings]

Hit *Render Animation* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F12</kbd>), wait for it to finish and the upload the generated *upload.mp4* next to your blend file to YouTube as described above.