# Cannot load any video/audio into VSE

Tags: video-sequence-editor, import, customization, versions

I created my own Blender build as I needed to add a "change font" option to the text effect in VSE (see here : https://developer.blender.org/D2424#a4349b1b)

But now Blender cannot load any video or audio format into the VSE. I'm getting the following error in the GUI :

> Report: Error /!\ File '/path/to/file/filename.ext' could not be loaded

and this in the stdout/terminal :

> $> not an anim : /path/to/file/filename.ext

As seen on this topic : [Cannot load movie files on Ubuntu](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28839/cannot-load-movie-files-on-ubuntu) I assume it could be an issue with the linking of my FFMPEG library or something with my CMakeLists.txt (which I didn't modify fyi). Thus, the preceding thread's solution is "Download precompiled version of Blender" which I don't want since I need the feature I implemented.

It may also be good to point out that I'm a total beginner with C++ (I only have some experience in C and web dev) and that I'm currently running Ubuntu 17.04.

Thank you for your time

Comment: that could quite easily depend from what you changed in sources, but you could also check if your compile toolchain can compile a "working" blender version (ie: it can load video/audio in vse, and work well generally) even without your source edits. If the "basic" compiled version works well, then it should be something you changed, imho. maybe you already tried, but I would check that first.