# What's the best output and encoding for 60fps animation?

Tags: file-format

I'm rendering an animation and I want it to be at 60fps. I plan to upload it to YouTube. So which file type format should I use: AVI JPEG, AVI Raw, H.264, MPEG, or Xvid? And what codec should I use?

So far I've used AVI format with H.264 codec. That seems to be working, but my computer isn't the best so I don't know if it's a format that actually supports 60fps. Any advice on this is greatly appreciate!

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24724/how-can-i-upload-blender-videos-to-youtube

Comment: Old question but for what it's worth I find the best results for me is using H.264 with Quicktime.