# Where are the bitrate settings?

Tags: rendering, video

I just installed blender for making youtube intros. I keep getting a "bitrate above max bitrate" sign whenever I render a video I made. So how do I change my bit rate?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I upload Blender videos to Youtube?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24724/how-can-i-upload-blender-videos-to-youtube)

Answer (score 6):

**UPDATE**: Starting with blender 2.79 the encoding options are available only if you enable **FFmpeg Video**.

A new section for **Encoding** is available then to choose the video container, codec and also the bitrate .

To manually input Bitrate settings the output quality must be set to

***None, use constant bit-rate***

[image]

**For older versions of blender:**

Bitrate is found under the encoding tab. Make sure you are on a video format so that the tab is visible.

The image contains some sample settings. Adjust them to fit your needs. [image: Encode Tab]

Answer (score 1):

Usually you don't even want to set the bitrate manually; having control over the quality of the output is often enough. Try lowering the quality setting, that'll also lower the average bitrate, but keeps a higher bitrate in fast-moving parts of the video, and allows a lower bitrate for simpler / static parts of the video.

By changing the encoding speed to something slower you can get the same quality at a lower bitrate, but at the expense of a slower export.