# Need Help Navigating Menus To Render File - Version 2.77 in Mac

Tags: video

I'm trying to create a custom 20th Century Fox animation. I have the pre-made template and I've changed text to what I want it to be. Last night I let it run in render mode to create the png files (per video I saw on how to render). Now I'm trying to render it as movie but I can not for the life of me figure out how to "select all" for the 600 frames for the project when I'm in "Video Editing" mode. I tried "Command A" (Mac version of select all) and it does not work. I'd really like not to have to click 600 times to select each file individually in order to add them in. Sample screens in tutorial video on Vimeo seem to be either on PC or a different version of Blender (I'm using 2.77 on Mac). Can someone PLEASE point me in right direction on where the output menu is to select what format movie file you want final movie file to be? I feel I'm so close to getting the animated file yet so far being these menus are so complicated and aren't in same place as the tutorial video I saw on Vimeo. Do I have to use the png files to render the animation or is there a way to do it directly? Also what's best format to use. I'm making a video project on site "Stupeflix" and will input it there. I'm completely exhausted trying to figure this out and I really want to finish this up to get into the birthday video I'm creating for my brother. Thanks all!

Comment: To select all the frames press A.

Answer (score 1):

The way to select all is just <kbd>A</kbd>. Don't push command.

Comment: Tried a previously without command but it didn't work. Just now tried a again and it DID work this time. But now how do I choose which video format. I do not see where to do that in the menus while in "Video Editing”! And what would be best format for video slideshow at site Stupeflix? Hate to spend hrs upon hrs rendering the animation and have it be wrong format.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Stupeflix but I would take a look at this answer for a general setup. http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/24727/26720

Answer (score -1):

I AM the original person who asked the question and the post that was removed was a response to the person who previously gave me more info. The site assigned me another temp user name when I returned. That's why the user name did not match. I have since created an account but have no idea how to merge this question with the responses with my account.

What I would like to know at this point is:  0
down vote

Thanks so much for link to the page. However, I've looked and looked and do not see how to even find "Properties Window" in Mac 2.77 version so I can change settings to continue. I'm usually pretty good with programs but this one is making me feel pretty stupid and/or blind! Can someone point me in right direction to find "Properties Window"?

If this isn't allowed to be posted then please by all means instruct me how it is I merge all of this into my account and not a temp user name? I really would like to find out how to finish this project for an upcoming 60th birthday party for my brother. I'm so close yet so far because I can't figure out where these buttons are even looking at video or word tutorials. Would appreciate any help. Thanks ! ! !

Comment: Read the [tour](http://blender.stackexchange.com/tour). It should explain some stuff.

Comment: Sure I can help you out. First please do not add a comment as an "answer." (that is why your first "answer" was deleted.) Now about your two accounts. I understand that both http://blender.stackexchange.com/users/28067/user28067 and  http://blender.stackexchange.com/users/28086/user28086 are yours, but both of those are unregistered accounts. (Did you create another account?) To register your newest account please click on the "register" link at the top of the page. After one of your accounts are registered we can merge them.

Comment: I did create an account from scratch in between coming back and now when I try to log in, it seems to indicate the account doesn't exist? I believe I created account using first guest name. Same email format used for the guest posts just replace 0730 in email address with thew word blend in the email address to hopefully find the account I created. Thanks much for the help and patience with this. It's much appreciated!

Comment: Please use the edit link on the original question. The answer section should not be used to clarify or to ask more questions.