# Resolution of video dropping when uploading video to youtube. Help please!

Tags: rendering

I have been working on a short film in eevee and I am finally ready to upload it to youtube however when I try to upload it the resolution drops dramatically. I rendered the animation in blender with the output settings in the picture below that I believe match what youtube recommends. Any suggestions on how I can improve or fix this issue? I have already had the video on youtube for a few days and the quality has not improved.

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24724/how-can-i-upload-blender-videos-to-youtube

Comment: Youtube does not usually upload the full-res version of your video when you upload it. Instead, it uploads a lower quality version first, then begins processing the higher resolution version. This can take a while so be patient. Inside the youtube studio, you can see if your uploaded video has had its HD version processed. You can also try changing the playback resolution inside the video player settings.