# Noise in the animation render

Tags: rendering, video, denoise, noise-reduction

So I did a render for a small animation that I need to put on a website ( needs to be small in size to load fast ). I used 500 samples in cycles with Denoise in this render but it seems to get some pixelation on smooth surfaces and when I then export the PNG sequence from AE or Premiere it gets way worst! Any ideas?

[image: Rendered straight from Blender]

[image: Exported Video full of artifacts]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid noisy renders in Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4980/how-to-avoid-noisy-renders-in-cycles)

Comment: I already did all that , with the Denoise etc. I think the main problem is the pos production program that compresses the hell out of the animation. How do you guy usually export an animation after blender ( maintaining the high quality without ending up with a huge file ? )

Comment: Related: [How to reduce the output video size?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/8864/78972)

Comment: Tried that already, I pixelates a lot and creates a lot of artefacts :/